# Normalize date to DD/MM/YYYY - redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using redux form and date picker as a component however user can input a date from keyboard as well. I want to use normalize prop from redux form to change the date into "MM/DD/YYYY" format so it user can just input numbers and after first two "/" is added and another two numbers the same. So for example when someone pastes "12122012" te value "12/12/2012" will be in the input.

Comment: Have you tried doing it on onChange?  

like : if(value.length==2)
           value=value+'/'

Comment: I want to do it only by redux form normalizing like here with normalize phone: https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/normalizing/

Answer (score 2):

Using Redux-form's `normalize` prop on the `<Field />` component, you can add this function to normalize dates to `mm/dd/YYYY` format.

```js
function normalizeDate(value, prevValue) {
  if (!value) return value;

  const valueOnlyNumbers = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  const prevValueOnlyNumbers = prevValue && prevValue.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

  // Enable backspacing:
  // if the user is backspacing and they backspace a forward slash, the date's
  // numbers won't be affected so just return the value.
  if (valueOnlyNumbers === prevValueOnlyNumbers) return value;

  const month = valueOnlyNumbers.slice(0, 2);
  const day = valueOnlyNumbers.slice(2, 4);
  const year = valueOnlyNumbers.slice(4, 8);

  if (valueOnlyNumbers.length < 2) return `${month}`;
  if (valueOnlyNumbers.length == 2) return `${month}/`;
  if (valueOnlyNumbers.length < 4) return `${month}/${day}`;
  if (valueOnlyNumbers.length == 4) return `${month}/${day}/`;
  if (valueOnlyNumbers.length > 4) return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
}
```